# Ways to pass data and/or value to View from Controller without ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

Just a short question, is there a way to pass data to View without using ViewData and TempData?

Besides model binding, are there any available method(s)?

RT: ViewModel is basically the same as model binding. Is there other way?

Thanks for the wonderful answers guys, much appreciation!

Comment: Using `ViewModel`

Comment: Why would you want to pass data the the other way? Your best bet is using a ViewModel.

Comment: I just want to know all the different methods to pass value to View. It is for my own knowledge.

Comment: `TempData`is for passing data between controller methods, not to a view. And the other alternative is `ViewBag`. But you should always be using a view model

Comment: You can use either `TempData`, `Session` or create your own viewmodel to do so. But the viewmodel class is the best to ensure strongly-typed data passed into view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the best simple way, it is using viewbag

Example :

In Controller :

```
ViewBag.Test="Hello Brother";
```

In View :

```
<input type="text" id="TXT" name="TXT" value=@ViewBag.Test/>
```

Or

```
<label>@ViewBag.Test</label>
```

Or Many Examples To Use it is very simple

i wish this help you brother